# Getting the permalink to the post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to append the facebook like button to each of the post on my blog. I have managed to get whatever I need to add the like button, the only thing I need is, how can I access the current post's link inside the function `author_bio_display($content)` i.e. at the place where it says `rawurlencode('post permalink goes here')`?

```
function author_bio_display($content)  
{  
        $bio_box = '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='. rawurlencode('post permalink goes here') .'&amp;layout=standard&amp;show-faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" id="facebook-like"></iframe>';

        return $content . $bio_box;  
}  

add_action("the_content", "author_bio_display");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are currently on a detail page i.e `single.php` here I have defined a variable `$post` and save current POST->ID in `$permalink`.Now you can play with it.

```
function author_bio_display($content)  
{  

        global $post;
        $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
        $bio_box = '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='. rawurlencode('*post permalink*') .'&amp;layout=standard&amp;show-faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" id="facebook-like"></iframe>';

        return $content . $bio_box;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the current ID without making a global $post variable:

```
$id = get_the_id();
```

And

```
get_permalink($id);
```

Most out-of-loop functions begin with "get_"  these functions do not echo but return data instead.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) is not an [`Action Hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), its a [`Filter Hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) so you should use `add_filter` instead of `add_action`.

```
function attach_like_button($content) {
  $post_id = $GLOBALS['post']->ID;
  $permalink = get_permalink($post_id);
  $link_button = ''; // Get latest facebook like button code from  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
  return $content.$link_button;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'attach_like_button' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do..

```
  $bio_box_id = get_permalink($post->ID);
  $bio_box = '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='. rawurlencode('*post permalink*') .'&amp;layout=standard&amp;show-faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" id="facebook-like"></iframe>';
  return $content . $bio_box;
```